# Как загрузить все изображения с сайта?

Tags: защита, изображения

Опишу суть проблемы. Мне нужно скачать все изображения из архива сайта.

[ссылка на сайт](http://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/nexsat-bin/nexsat.cgi?BASIN=CONUS&SUB_BASIN=focus_regions&AGE=Archive&REGION=NW_Pacific&PRODUCT=vis_ir_background&SUB_PRODUCT=goes&SIZE=Full&DISPLAY=Single&PATH=NW_Pacific/Overview/vis_ir_background/gms_6_lowcloud&DIR=/nexsat_data/PUBLIC/CONUS/focus_regions/NW_Pacific/Overview/vis_ir_background/gms_6_lowcloud&NUM=50&ARROW=next&SECTOR=Overview&&buttonPressed=Archive)

Я открыл html, достал оттуда все имена изображений, сформировал правильные ссылки, но оказалось, что по ссылкам мне отдается пустая страница. Оказалось, что пока я по изображению на сайте в архиве не нажму, оно у меня не загрузится.
Т.е. все прокликанные изображения открываются нормально. Причем с двух разных ИП в одной подсети тоже все работает. Т.е. могу кликнуть на изображении из архива в одном, и оно будет открываться нормально на другом компе по прямой ссылке.

Проверить можно так: открыть какое-нибудь изображение, изменить его URL на адрес другого изображения, поменяв дату в адресе, - изображение открыться не должно.

Вопрос: как мне без прокликивания скачать все изображения?
Как реализована подобная защита, если я ее на свой сайт хочу запилить?

Answer (score 1):

Покажи адреса изображений, которые ты скопировал с сайта.

Я копирую и все открывается. Пример http://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/htdocs_dyn_server/PUBLIC/nexsat/thumbs/full_size/NW_Pacific/Overview/vis_ir_background/gms_6_lowcloud/20141127.0457.mtsat_1r.visir.bckgrlowcldngt.NW_Pacific_Overview.DAY.jpg

Comment: Вообще, программа teleport pro в свое время очень помогала в скачивании сайтов целиком или изображений со страниц.

Comment: замените в ссылке время на 0513. У меня она не открывается. Как только кликну по ней в архиве все откроется.

Comment: Вот здесь лежат все доступные фотографии и, соответственно, время за какой-то период.
http://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/nexsat-bin/nexsat.cgi?BASIN=CONUS&SUB_BASIN=focus_regions&AGE=Prev&REGION=NW_Pacific&PRODUCT=vis_ir_background&SUB_PRODUCT=goes&SIZE=Thumb&DISPLAY=Mosaic&PATH=NW_Pacific/Overview/vis_ir_background/gms_6_lowcloud&DIR=/nexsat_data/PUBLIC/CONUS/focus_regions/NW_Pacific/Overview/vis_ir_background/gms_6_lowcloud&NUM=50&ARROW=next&SECTOR=Overview&CURRENT=20141127.0430.mtsat_1r.visir.bckgrlowcldngt.NW_Pacific_Overview.DAY.jpg&&buttonPressed=Mosaic